# Partially applied recursive functions

Tags: scala, recursion, partial-application

```
def mainCaller() = { 
  val name = "xyz"
  someList.foreach { u:Map => foo(name, u) }
}

def foo(name:String)(map:Map): Unit = {
  //match case....
  //recursive call to foo in each case where name remains same, but map changes
}
```

how can I write foo as a partially applied function, where I dont have to pass name in every recursive call and just call `foo(map1)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options:

```
def foo(name:String)(map:Map): Unit = {
    val bar = foo(name)_
    //match case...
    // case 1:
    bar(x)

    // case 2:
    bar(y)
}
```

Or:

```
def foo(name:String): Map => Unit = {
    def bar(map: Map): Unit = {
        //match case...
        // case 1:
        bar(x)

        // case 2:
        bar(y)
    }
    bar
}
```

Comment: Simply brilliant!! 
Do the two have any advantages and disadvantages. 
The first method looks much cleaner.

Comment: @scout: I can't think of any (dis)advantages for either. I made a mistake btw. In the first example it needs an underscore after `foo(name)`.